# Create a list of function at compile time

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

for a small test framework I am trying to create a list of function at compile time.
I am creating a test function with a macro and want to be able to call all of the added testx from main.

```
#define ADD_TEST(X) my_test_##X

ADD_TEST(foo){
    ASSERT_EQ(1, 2);
}
ADD_TEST(bar){
    ...
}

int main (void){
    something_calling_all_my_tests();
    return 0;
}
```

A full example in C++ would be http://pastebin.com/C5mmcYDD

regards

Comment: Get them from the linker map file.

Comment: would need a third party software to do it which isn't what I am looking for

Comment: That "third party software" - the linker - will be needed in order to create an executable program.   In other words, whether you use it for this purpose or not, you will need to use it.

Comment: getting the list is one thing, then you need to write the code that will call the function in the list or am I missing something?

Comment: Declare an array of pairs of names and function pointers, let a script generate this array in a separate .c file, and let your build tool link that to the final executable. It's without doubt the easiest way, unless you find an existing unit test framework for C.

Comment: Why do you wish to remove the possibility of just running one or two tests and only have the option of running all of them?

Comment: The C++ example, doesn't use metaprogramming. Can't you simply implement the equivalent C version?

Comment: @MargaretBloom It uses non-constant expressions as static initialisers, which is not allowed in standard C.

Comment: @Rhymoid Yes, but you can easily get around that.

Comment: @MargaretBloom I'd love to see how that's possible.

Comment: @Rhymoid Correct me If I'm wrong, isn't the std:vector created at runtime before main?

Comment: @MargaretBloom Yes, it is. But while that's obviously allowed in standard C++, standard C doesn't have any facilities for that, as far as I know.

Comment: @Rhymoid Ahhh, I see, the OP want to "annotate" the test functions. I see what you mean.

Comment: I'm not convinced that you may not be looking for the `constructor` and `destructor` attributes that create entries in the `.ctors` and `.dtors` section of the object file. You can place references to functions in either section in one of three ways. (1) using either the `section` attribute; (2) `constructor` and `destructor` attributes or (3) with an inline-assembly call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using **attribute** ((constructor)) we can run the function before the main and register each test function. It's not a compile time, but fit my needs so far.

```
#define ADD_TEST(TEST_NAME) void test_##TEST_NAME (void);       \
  void  t_##TEST_NAME##_registerFunction (TestFunction test_##TEST_NAME)__attribute__ ((constructor)); \
  void  t_##TEST_NAME##_registerFunction (TestFunction test_##TEST_NAME){n++; printf("running %s\n", #TEST_NAME);} \
  void test_##TEST_NAME (void)
```